# data.stackexchange.com/help is broken

Tags: bug, data-explorer, help-center, broken-link

https://data.stackexchange.com/help yields a Runtime Error:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.

---

> ### Runtime Error
>
> **Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details
> of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security
> reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the
> local server machine.
>
> **Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a `<customErrors>` tag
> within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory
> of the current web application. This `<customErrors>` tag should then
> have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: P.S. Thanks for upgrading the hardware and for adding beta sites to Data Explorer!